# unable to update path on mac os mavericks

Tags: macos, bash, path, export

Here is the contents of my .bash_profile

```
PS1=">>"


alias ls='ls -G'
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad

#set SCALA_HOME variable.
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/bin/scala

# Added by Canopy installer on 2014-09-22
# VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT can be set to '' to make bashprompt show that Canopy is active, otherwise 1

VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source /Users/muralidharn/canopy/bin/activate

#add ipython path to actual PATH variable.
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/muralidharn/canopy/bin

#set JAVA_HOME , this is the way mac recommends that we do it.
#export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

#add maven to path
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/muralidharn/apache-maven-3.2.3/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/mynewpath
# Added by Canopy installer on 2014-09-22
# VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT can be set to '' to make bashprompt show that Canopy is active, otherwise 1
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source /Users/muralidharn/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate
```

My PATH variable is not getting updated with any of the paths that I am exporting. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong as I have a feeling its something very silly that I'm just not seeing. I tried restarting the terminal , restarting my computer , source .bash_profile etc... already.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: do you have `~/.profile` too? Just add the `set -x` to the start of your `~/.bash_profile` and/or `~/.profile` and open a new terminal.app window - you will see what and how thigs are changing.. (ofc, remove the `set -x` afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work for you, but I would give this syntax a try:

```
export PATH=\
/usr/local/bin:\
/usr/local/sbin:\
/opt/local/bin:\
/opt/local/sbin:\
$HOME/Dropbox/bin:\
$HOME/bin:\
$HOME/usr:\
/usr/X11/bin:\
/usr/bin:\
/bin:\
/usr/sbin:\
/sbin:\
/Homes/usr/local/bin:\
/vnmr/bin:\
$HOME/Rosetta/main/source/bin
```

(obviously, use your paths above. This is just an example of how I set mine up).

---

Also, put this at the top of your bash profile:

```
#!/bin/bash
```